# Laravel model is only returning results half of the time

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have this method called `show()` which will fetch destinations from the database but it first checks for a `location` key in the input provided.

```
public function show()
{
  // Fetch the appropriate destinations
  if (Input::has('location')) {
    $destinations = Destination::where('type', '=', Input::get('type'))
      ->where('city', '=', Input::get('location'))
      ->with('city', 'state', 'type')
      ->get();
  } else {
    $destinations = Destination::where('type', '=', Input::get('type'))
      ->with('city', 'state', 'type')
      ->get();
  }
  \Log::debug($destinations);
  return $destinations;
```

This works perfectly fine, but only half the time. Sometimes it returns an empty array (`[]`) and sometimes it returns all of the results as expected.

At first I thought it was my JavaScript but it turns out logging this directly to the console from the PHP is also returning an empty array most of the time, but not always.

What would possibly cause something like this to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure you always pass exact same data (log also input data). For example one you pass "Hanover" and second time " Hanover" - it looks almost same, but will change results totally. So probably you should add trimming your data (if you are not doing it already).

Another potential issue is here:

```
$destinations = Destination::where('type', '=', Input::get('type'))
      ->where('city', '=', Input::get('location'))
      ->with('city', 'state', 'type')
      ->get();
```

Do you have `city` column in `destinations` table? If so, do you have also relationship with name `city`?  It seems as error for me + in addition you should never create relationship with same name as column in table in database or you'll get into trouble sooner or later.

Comment: There's definitely appropriate data in the request. There is indeed a `city` column in the `destinations` table. I didn't know that was a bad thing to do but it's readable and since I've come this far I'd rather face the trouble it may cause instead of avoiding it just because. Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: @Arcrammer I don't tell you it's a bad thing to have column `city` in your table. But if you do, you should change `city` relationship to something else for example `relatedCity` and same in `with`

Comment: Oh, yeah! I've already made _that_ mistake before haha. Thanks for the warning. I've just discovered my JavaScript is actually sending the wrong data, so you were right about the data thing. The method expects an integer but my script is returning a string which breaks it. Thank you!